# Check if product with category "A" is in the cart and apply a 10% discount to all products with category "B" in the cart:

Tags: woocommerce, product, categories, cart, discount

I'm trying to add a 10% discount to all products that fall into category B when a product from category A is in the cart, this is what i've tried so far and from what I see there's not an obvious reason but the discount is not applied in the cart. It can be a total discount fee or a separate discount for each item.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_category_discount_in_cart', 10, 1 );

function apply_category_discount_in_cart( $cart ) {

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

  if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;

  $discount_amount = 0;
  $category_A_in_cart = false;

  // Loop through each item in the cart
  foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // Check if the product has category A
    if ( has_term( 'categorya', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
      $category_A_in_cart = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If a product with category A is found in the cart
  if ( $category_A_in_cart ) {
    // Loop through each item in the cart again
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product = $cart_item['data'];

      // Check if the product has category B
      if ( has_term( 'categoryb', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $discount_amount += $cart_item['line_total'] * 0.1;
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['data']->get_price() * 0.9 );
      }
    }

    // Add the discount amount as a fee
    $cart->add_fee( 'Discount', -$discount_amount, true );
  }

}
```

Comment: The code looks OK and it works well for me, both product price and cart fee are applied on cart page.  The problem is probably somewhere else. Also, keep in mind that if you reduce the prices of products and then apply a negative discount value of reduced sum on top of that, the cart will end up with doubled discount (20% total instead of 10).

Comment: @KristiánFilo Yes I've been trying both a fee and and reducing the price to see if perhaps the problem is betwen one of them and I forgot to remove it, but I also can't understand why the category is not being picked up from the cart items correctly

Comment: The `has_term` conditions look fine to me as well. If you remove them, is it working?